# Not able to install Ubuntu 12.04 in VMWare workstation 9 - Operating System not found Error

Tags: 12.04

Getting this error Operating System not found when trying to install Ubuntu through ISO file .

If i install with the option of giving the path to the iso image stored on my system.
I get a message down that the operating system could not be detected.

Even if go install using the option i will install OS later and set the iso image path in VM settings. when i power on the VM i get Operating System Not Found error.
Please Help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To get a better answer and to help other users who may experience a similar problem, please edit your question with more information on the problem. Even a screenshot can be useful!

Comment: @Tim Fothergill  thanks for the advice. done. not able to upload image. and can u plz help me on the error.

Comment: How are you installing?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the ISO's SHA sum.
- Try specifying manually the boot drive with pressing "ESC" at boot.
- Check your HDD in the VM if the manual boot is not working.

Easiest way it to re-create the VM and that will make sure your CD is connected, and the HDD boots properly.

Comment: how to i check the SHA sum? and i have tried specifyng the boot drive manually. But nothing works

Comment: Alright. Re-create the VM, and what OS do you use? If you are on Windows, you can use this: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html . SHA1 sums are here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ ("**SHA1SUMS**" file.)

Comment: i checked out the links you gave, but i am sorry i dont understand as to what relation does the SHA sum have to do with this? and my OS is windows 7 32 bits.

Comment: and i have downloaded the ubuntu ISO file from their website which i am using for the installation

Comment: can some one reply on  this

Comment: Did you create a new VM? Is it still not working?